# Short CV and publication list

Tags: cv

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When should I stop including talks on my cv?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/1280/when-should-i-stop-including-talks-on-my-cv)

I am considering splitting my academic CV into a short version (ideally less than two pages) and a longer one with a full list of publications and talks.

Q1: do you think it is a good idea to split it into two?

Q2: which ones of those would you put in the shorter version?

- list of most important papers (5?)
- list of most important talks
- research grants and awards
- other scientific service (refereeing, conference organization)
- schools attended

Comment: See the linked question above; the answers there should be exactly what you're looking for.