# Should CV include special note about published 'cover articles'?

Tags: publications, cv

I just published an article and, when I saw the journal, I was surprised to discover that they put my article on the cover.

My question is, should I update my CV to make special note of the fact that my article was not just published but is the cover story in a particular journal?

Comment: I did. Rather one should... the answers to this question are probably helpful: http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/1280/when-should-i-stop-including-talks-on-my-cv?rq=1. Early in your career this might be useful. Later in your career, not so.

Comment: I also say yes. In some respect this is the equivalent of an award for excellence, after all the paper was picked out for one reason or another.

Comment: Yes, you should indicate a cover article just like you might an invited article. Putting (Cover article) or a similar designation would be entirely appropriate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A cover article is noteworthy, but not all noteworthy material goes on all CVs. I include a note about cover articles on my CV iff I am also including citation counts. I only include this extra information if the CV is for something that is trying to evaluate the "impact" of my research.