# How to list this accomplishment on my vita?

Tags: cv, tenure-track, awards

I just saw that one of my research articles was the most-read paper in one of the top journals in my field in February of this year.  What is the appropriate way, if any, to list this on a vita?  It's not an "Award", strictly speaking, so would it be best to just list it as a comment next to the paper?

Comment: Related (not exact duplicate): http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/9894/should-cv-include-special-note-about-published-cover-articles

Comment: And, just to be pedantic, it's "vitae", not "vita".

Answer (score 6):

Great work ! The way I do it is under the Publications section of my CV. The following citation is formatted in the ACM style. You can modify it for your own citation styles.

**J1**. Smith, J. 2013. "The best paper ever". *ACM Transactions of Awesomeness*, 1 (4). ACM Press, NY, USA. (**most read article in March 2013**)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, congratulations!

Secondly, whether or not to include this in your CV depends what you are applying for - if you are applying for positions that involve research, then yes, add it as a comment next to the paper.  Then again, it probably would not hurt just to have a comment about it in there anyway.